# Typing in the value of an input doesn't change the .val() of the input?

Tags: jquery

Screenshot 1: Unchanged:

[image]

Screenshot 2: Changed, yet .val() shows original :

[image]

.val() always returns the same thing, because in the HTML, the text inbetween the `<textarea>` tags remains the same.

```
<textarea id="suggested_text" name="suggested_text" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;">Enter your comment(s) then click submit.</textarea>
```

How do I get this to behave normally? so I can actually retrieve the value of what is typed in the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
$("#suggested_text").html()
```

instead!

You may see it live:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6rmb/

EDIT:
Just realized that on the link above I used .val(), so it also worked fine for me and html as I first proposed not!!!

Comment: Agreed; not sure why it wouldn't be updated in the bottom code snippet, but retrieving the value of a textarea should probably be done with .text() or .html()

Comment: This doesn't change anything, as far as I can tell. jQuery is smart enough to check the textarea's HTML when you call `val()` on it. [PROOF](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVqeq/1/)

Comment: if I use text(), html(), or val(), it still just get the default text. Is there some special instance you can think of where these functions only return the value of the textarea from onpageload?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NFM9z/.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

`.val()` is a valid method for accessing the values within a `textarea`.

Have you tried to access the value outside of the console, manually writing to the console when the textarea is changed (I would suggest to attach a blur() event handler to the textarea to write to the value to the console), or possibly with [Opera's Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)?